# TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting when using the modulo operator

Tags: python

I am trying to use the modulo operator in this function that prints the highest even number in a list, but I always get this error:

```
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Code:

```
def largest_even():
    """
    -------------------------------------------------------
    Returns the largest even number.
    Use: result = largest_even()
    -------------------------------------------------------
    Preconditions:

    Postconditions:
        returns
        result - largest even number
    -------------------------------------------------------
    """
    num = int(input('Enter a number:'))
    n_list = []
    while num != "":
        n_list.append(num)
        num = input('Next number:')
    print(n_list)
    n = 0
    e_list = []
    while n < len(n_list):
        a = (n_list[n]) % 2
        if a == 0:
            e_list.append(n_list[n])
        n = n + 1
    print(n)
    print(e_list)
    if len(e_list) == 0:
        result = 'False'
    result = e_list[0]
    n = 0
    while n < len(e_list):
        if e_list[n] > result:
            result = e_list[n]
    print("{} is the largest even number in that list.".format(result))
```

Comment: That's **not** the modulo operator. `n_list[n]` is evidently a *string*, you're invoking C-style string formatting: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#old-string-formatting.

Comment: File "C:\Users\mben6270\Downloads\mben6270_a7\mben6270_a7\src\a7_functions.py", line 56, in largest_even
    a = (n_list[n]) % 2
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Comment: Error is in this line:                                                                                          a = (n_list[n]) % 2

Answer (score 0):

You only add one number to the list; inside the loop, you are adding strings.

```
num = input('Enter a number:')
n_list = []
while num != "":
    n_list.append(int(num))
    num = input('Next number:')
```